# Angular - Select array in json object

Tags: json, angularjs

I have a json object of arrays that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John Smith",
        "age": 52
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Jane Walters",
        "age": 43
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Mike Wilson",
        "age": 65
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Tom Samuels",
        "age": 29
    }
]
```

I am displaying all these names on the "index" page, and I want to show only one on each of the "character/[id]" pages. Here is my controller for the index page:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
    controller('index', ['$scope', 'characters', function($scope, c){
        $scope.characters = c.getCharacters;
    }]);
```

Aaand here's the "characters" service:

```
factory('characters', function($resource){
    return $resource('JSON/characters.json', {}, 
    {
        'getCharacters':    {method: 'GET', isArray:true}
    }); 
});
```

The views are the standard boilerplate.

My problem is, how do I create a service (or manipulate the object in the controller) for the "character/[id]" route so it only selects a single array based on the JSON id?

I did the phonecat demo on angularjs.org, but that demo uses separate JSON files for each phone, and then one big JSON file for the index page. I want to avoid that.

One final thing: I am using angular-seed, so I'd like to maintain the syntax used there. I've tried lots of different approaches with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Example in my own proyect:

The controller:

```
app.controller("prodDetalleController", ["$scope","$http","$routeParams", function($scope,$http,$routeParams ){    

  vm = this;
  $scope.id = $routeParams.idProducto;


    // Listado de productos
    $http.get("_producto.php?id="+$scope.id)
    .success(function (respuesta) 
    {
        vm.producto = respuesta;}
    )
    .error(function(){
        vm.producto = "Error: no hay datos.";
    }); 

}]); // fin ctrl
```

And in PHP:

```
<?php

 $id = $_GET['id'];
 //echo $id;

$conn = @new mysqli('localhost', 'root','buenosaires','martin_db');

$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE idProducto=$id");

$myArray = array();
```

...

And in view:

```
{{producto.titulo}}
{{producto.descripcion}}
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are asking how you can get id from the route url.

define your character route path like:

```
/character/:id
```

and in your character controller like

```
....controller('characterCtrl', ['$scope', 'characters','$routeParams' function($scope, c,$params){
    $scope.characters = c.getCharacters;
    //you have $params.id here as the id from the url
}]);
```

on the commented line loop through the `$scope.characters` to find the one with matching id and set that to another scope variable. 
A jsFiddle with your current pages/view and controllers could be more useful while helping.

Comment: I would loop through the array in the controller, but it is empty till loaded in the browser